# Sending mail not showing all filled forms in inbox using PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm kind of new to this. I have been working around this from someone a while about sending a mail from an HTML form to my inbox and want to display the filled inputs in my inbox with other messages to display in the inbox.

**index.html**

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
    <section id="left">
        <label for="form_name">Name</label>
        <input name="form_name" id="form_name" type="text" >
        <label for="form_email">Email</label>
        <input name="form_email" id="form_email" type="email" >
        <label for="form_msg">Message</label>
        <textarea name="form_msg" id="form_msg"></textarea>
        <input id="submit" class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="send">
    </section>
</form>
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['form_name'];
    $email = $_POST['form_email'];
    $message = $_POST['form_msg'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone_no'];
    //send email
    mail("myemail@gmail.com", "This is a Reservation  from:" ,Name. ':' . $name, $email, $phone);
    }
?>
```

**mail.js**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "email.php",
   data: $(form).serialize(),
   success: function(){
   $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mail("kondasmajid@gmail.com", "This is a Reservation  from:" ,Name. ':' . $name, $email, $phone);
```

...that line won't lead nowhere. In PHP, you have to concatenate strings through a dot, so the following line should work:

```
mail("kondasmajid@gmail.com", 
  "This is a Reservation  from: Name:" . $name . ", Email: " . $email . ", Phone: " . $phone);
```

Comment: Mostly true. You can concatenate with a comma when using it as part of an echo statement. `echo $name, $email, $phone;`.

Comment: Good  but im getting this

` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /homepages/16/d623133395/htdocs/jewimahotal/mail.php on line 12`

Comment: Sorry, I've got a typo in there. See my corrected answer in a minute

Comment: @NicoHaase please any stuffs for me

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that - how can I help you further?